# Add to cart takes too much of time in magento2.2.4?

Tags: addtocart, magento2.2.4

Actually, I tried to add the product to cart but it takes so much of time.

I have disabled the cache while i am in the developing this website.

How to rectify this time delaying issue?

Comment: have you enable cache?

Comment: no disabled the cache

Comment: Which mode enabled, default/developer?

Comment: I disabled the cache in cache management and I didn't know which mode it is default/developer  .can you please tell me how to know which mode

Comment: @nukalasatish Have you got any solution?

Comment: yes I got the solution Gem thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can check mode by below command

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

You can set developer

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

You can enable cache

php bin/magento cache:enable

After setup developer and enable cache, you can check add to cart time.